# How to log when enter and exit API in .net CORE 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I would like to log when I enter and exit the API. I see that I have to use a `DelegatingHandler` and use the method

```
protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

But I don t know how to implement this in CORE API 6.
I want you to know that I need to initialize an object for log in the delegatingHandler

Here an example :

```
public class LoggingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private ApiLog _logIn;

    private ApiLog _logOut;

    public MessageLoggingHandler(string _conString, string  TypeLog)
    {
        _logIn = new ApiLog(_conString,TypeLog);
        _logOut = new ApiLog(_conString, TypeLog);
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logIn.AddIncomingLog(request);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        if (response.Content != null)
        {
            _logOut.AddOutgoingLog(response);
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

I'm starting in the Web API Core.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how to set the delegate for httpclient which send the request to the web api.

I suggest you could use the `AddHttpMessageHandler` method.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("test").AddHttpMessageHandler<LoggingHandler>();
```

About how to use it, you could use IHttpClientFactory to create it.

Like below:

```
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(
    HttpMethod.Get,
    "https://api.github.com/repos/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/branches")
        {
            Headers =
        {
            { HeaderNames.Accept, "application/vnd.github.v3+json" },
            { HeaderNames.UserAgent, "HttpRequestsSample" }
        }
        };
        var httpclient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("test");

        var httpResponseMessage = await httpclient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);

    }
```

Comment: Hi, What is "Test" on AddHttpClient("test") and where can i initialize LoggingHandler with his parameter on the constructor.  I want to log the request and response

Comment: Test is the httpclient name, _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("test")